# Python reading scientific numbers from file in array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to read scientific numbers from file into array.
Right now when i read file , numbers are pushed in array as strings.

**REQUIREMENT:**
Kindly note that I want scientific numbers to be intact , not converted into floats, they should be in array as they are in file. No conversion to float. This is requirement.

1. **wrong** : ['8.201E-02', '8.82562E-05', '1.26080E-05', '1.23251E+01', '2.00000E-20', '9.600E-02']
2. **Right** : [8.201E-02, 8.82562E-05, 1.26080E-05, 1.23251E+01, 2.00000E-20, 9.600E-02]

**Code:**

```
data = open("numbers.txt", "r").read().split('\n')
  print data
#['8.201E-02', '8.82562E-05', '1.26080E-05', '1.23251E+01', '2.00000E-20', '9.600E-02']
```

**Numbers.txt:**

```
8.201E-02
8.82562E-05
1.26080E-05
1.23251E+01
2.00000E-20
9.600E-02
```

Comment: But these **are** float numbers.

Comment: So what do you want then?

Comment: that's not how computers work, I'm afraid

Comment: yes, i want the numbers to be intact as exponential numbers not converted into decimals without e.

Comment: @django the "scientific notation" is just a convenient way of printing floats

Comment: WHAT do you want exactly ? your RIGHT example shows an array of float ...

Comment: @tobias_k.representation  must be in e form in array. I know i can use format to print but format will convert it to string.

Comment: @django : You completely misunderstand how floating point numbers work in informatics.

Comment: @django: as I said above that's not how computers work. Computers don't use this kind of notation.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand: what you want is them displayed as exponential format

I would load them, convert to float, then when printing, display as scientific format

```
with open("numbers.txt", "r") as fh:
   data=map(float,fh.read().split('\n'))
```

then when displaying use something like :

```
['%e' % (x) for x in data]
```

*EDIT*:

- used with primitive as suggested (better)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
data = map(Decimal, data)
```

with the appropriate precision set for Decimals. Check [the Python doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
print np.loadtxt('numbers.txt',delimiter="\n")
```

Seems to do the trick